# Is there any way to convert xarray time to datetime in NetCDF file?

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I'm trying to convert time to DateTime format with xarray, but without success. This is what I've tried so far (see code below), it seems Pandas read the time as milliseconds. My dataset does not have any calendar in the dataset:

```
da  = xr.open_dataset(file.nc, decode_times=False)
da['DATE'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(da['DATE'].values)
```

output:

```
datetime64[ns]
1970-01-01T00:00:01.577923200 .....
array(['1970-01-01T00:00:01.577923200', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578009600',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578096000', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578182400',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578268800', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578355200',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578441600', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578528000',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578614400', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578700800',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578787200', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578873600',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.578960000', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579046400',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579132800', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579219200',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579305600', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579392000',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579478400', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579564800',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579651200', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579737600',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579824000', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579910400',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.579996800', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.580083200',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.580169600', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.580256000',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:01.580342400', '1970-01-01T00:00:01.580428800'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I already tried:
`xr.apply_ufunc(mdnum2date)`

but arises this error:

```
'DataArray' object has no attribute 'apply_ufunc'.
```

Comment: If there’s no calendar information, then xarray has no way to do this automatically. Can you provide more information about the values in the DATE array, including examples, data type, and the desired interpretation/units?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime # Python standard library datetime module
from netCDF4 import Dataset,netcdftime,num2date # http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/
file_in = Dataset("file.nc","r",format="NETCDF4")
tname = "time_variable_name"
nctime = file_in.variables[tname][:] # get values
t_unit = file_in.variables[tname].units # get unit  "days since 1950-01-01T00:00:00Z"
t_cal = file_in.variables[tname].calendar
tvalue = num2date(nctime,units = t_unit,calendar = t_cal)
str_time = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for i in tvalue] # to display dates as string
```

You'll need [NetCDF4](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/) installed for this to work.